# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: In Intellij [Spring boot]

Tags: java, spring, maven

**I am receiving the following errors with maven: UPDATED**

**Error when running the application(just start code with database setting)**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer

**ERROR While mvn install**

[ERROR] initializationError(com.example.polls.PollsApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>polls</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>polls</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For Working with Json Web Tokens (JWT) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Java 8 Date/Time Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**The Only Start Code**

```
package com.example.polls;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PollsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PollsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Spring boot, and this project I want to learn combine react and spring boot together. I refer to a tech blog link: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-spring-security-jwt-mysql-react-app-part-1/

Comment: Seems like a version mismatch. Can you try purging your local repo?

Comment: Why there is no component scan in application class

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the spring-boot-starter-parent not being picked up.  Try getting rid of the `<relativePath/>`, and let the version be pulled from the Maven Central Repo.  So the `<parent>` definition should just be:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I had or saw a similar problem when I tried to create an application without using the Spring Boot parent.  Another post (sorry I can't credit it) pointed me to this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent which helped me out, but since you want to use it, then the issue is simply that the `spring-boot-starter-parent` is not being picked up.